# Call julia from Mathematica?

Tags: interoperability, julia

How might one go about calling julia from Mathematica? And vice versa?

I'm aware of the MathLink.jl package (https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MathLink.jl), which I've installed into julia 1.3.1.

I also installed the Mathematica.jl package (), but the julia command `using Mathematica` (after `using MathLink`) produces errors when precompiling the package.

Comment: This is coming in 12.1

Comment: @user5601: I don't see it in the 12.1 docs, and `ExternalEvaluate["Julia", "2+2"]` seems to fail.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Julia.html and https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureJuliaForExternalEvaluate.html might be helpful.

Comment: The workflow's configuration information for Julia did get it working.

Answer (score 10):

Turn the comment into an answer. The functionality is available (as EXPERIMENTAL) in *v12.1*. One can refer to the following pages in the document:

["Julia" (External Evaluation System)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/externalevaluationsystem/Julia.html)

[Configure Julia for ExternalEvaluate](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/ConfigureJuliaForExternalEvaluate.html)